# React.Js styled-components getting this error

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

> ERROR in ./src/components/Login.js 4:0-39
>
> Module not found: Error: Cannot find file:
> 'styled-components.browser.esm.js' does not match the corresponding
> name on disk:
> '.\node_modules\styled-Components\dist\styled-components'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an installation problem. Run/type in command line

```
npm install --save styled-components
```

and then restart your app, by running `npm start`

If you use yarn, replace npm with yarn.

Let us know if the issue resolves!

Comment: Error: Cannot find file: 'styled-components.browser.esm.js' does not match the corresponding 
name on disk: '.\node_modules\styled-Components\dist\styled-components'.
 @ ./src/App.js 6:0-39
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 10:33-36  

this error still there even after doing npm install --save styled-components and restarting the app